# is it possible to link the zlib when genreate so with gcc

Tags: gcc, shared-library

I need to invoke the c method from rust. Fisrt step, I am using gcc to generate a so file like this:

```
gcc -shared *.o -o libsynctex_parser.so
```

But when I build the rust project, it shows that the c source code missing some function, the missing function was come from zlib. So is it possible to package the zlib into the distinate so? I have tried this but it seems did not work:

```
gcc -shared *.o -o libsynctex_parser.so -lz
```

Comment: What is your goal here? To statically link libz into the resulting .so? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc -shared *.o -o libsynctex_parser.so
```

You can obtain compression library sources and compile them,
then they will be part of the `*.o` objects.
Equivalently you could obtain object files with `ar x libz.a`.
The rust link edit will then succeed.
The compression deps will be statically linked.

But that's not what you want.

Keep producing libsynctex_parser.so just as you have been.
Append `-lz` to the end of the rust link edit line.
Now the compression deps will be dynamically linked,
which is what you want as it conserves memory
and will do the Right Thing when security updates come out.